# can not add UILabel to view

Tags: iphone

I am trying to add a UILabel anagrammatically like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]]];

    [self loadAndDrawButtons];
    CGRect  frame       =   CGRectMake(357, 240, 48, 42);
    CGRect  frame       =   CGRectMake(357, 200, 48, 42);
    UILabel *myLabel    =   [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [myLabel setText:@"THIS"];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [myLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];

    [myLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    [self.view  addSubview:myLabel];
}
```

So first I set the background for **view** and then I also display some button on the view. Background and button are successfully loaded. Eventually, I am adding a UILabel to **view** and I end up with nothing....
I am thinking that the background and my button will hide my UILabel( I know this is not right way but also give it a try) so that I comment out

> //    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]]];
>
> //    [self loadAndDrawButtons];

Now my view is blank without my UILable...
Could any one give my a hint about this problem...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem likes in the label frame:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(357, 200, 48, 42);
```

which is relative to its superview coordinates in this case your view is at the most 320 x 480 (or at least thats how much the screen can show without scrolling) however you are providing a an x value of 357 (greater than 320), which means the label is not being drawn within the visible portion of the view.

Comment: yeah you are rite.. i did not pay attention to the dimension. when I do this **CGRect frame = CGRectMake(200, 357, 48, 42);**. The UILabel is loaded and displayed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(357, 200, 48, 42);

**357 is the x origin of the label ..**
Iphone has limit of 320 in x direction ..change it to a lower value than 320

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you set the frame outside of the screen? I assumed this is iPhone app, in portrait view, 357 is definitely out of screen

try this maybe

```
CGRect  frame = CGRectMake(180, 240, 48, 42);
```